# Spark: fail to run the terasort when the amount of data gets bigger

Tags: apache-spark

I have a spark bench which includes a terasort and it run properly when data is only a few hundred of GB,but when i generate more data such as 1 TB, it went wrong in some step.The following is my code:

```
import org.apache.spark.rdd._
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._


object ScalaTeraSort{

  def main(args: Array[String]){
    if (args.length < 2){
      System.err.println(
        s"Usage: $ScalaTeraSort <INPUT_HDFS> <OUTPUT_HDFS>"
      )
      System.exit(1)
    }
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("ScalaTeraSort")
    val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)

    val file = sc.textFile(args(0))
    val data = file.map(line => (line.substring(0, 10), line.substring(10)))
                     .sortByKey().map{case(k, v) => k + v}
    data.saveAsTextFile(args(1))

    sc.stop()
  }
```

}

this code mainly includes 3 steps: sortByKey, map and saveAsTextFile. it seems there is no wrong in the first two step but when it comes to the third step,it went wrong all the times and then retried the second step. the third step went wrong because of ***"FetchFailed(BlockManagerId(40, sr232, 44815, 0), shuffleId=0, mapId=11825, reduceId=0)"***

Comment: `FetchFailed` isn't really the cause. What is the first or underlying error?

Comment: 14 14/10/08 14:33:53 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 160.0 in stage 1.1 (TID 46245, sr200): FetchFailed(BlockManagerId(14, sr229, 55202, 0), shuffleId=0, mapId=11709, reduceId=160)
 15 14/10/08 14:33:53 INFO DAGScheduler: Resubmitting failed stages
 16 14/10/08 14:33:53 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 206.0 in stage 1.1 (TID 46291, sr200): FetchFailed(BlockManagerId(30, sr168, 46857, 0), shuffleId=0, mapId=12720, reduceId=206)
 17 14/10/08 14:33:53 INFO DAGScheduler: Resubmitting Stage 2 (map at ScalaTeraSort.scala:45) and Stage 1 (saveAsTextFile at ScalaTeraSort.scala:47) due to fetch failure

Answer (score 4):

I found out the reason, the essential problem is : ***java.io.IOException: sendMessageReliably failed because ack was not received within 60 sec***

that is to say,you have to set the property "spark.core.connection.ack.wait.timeout" to a bigger value, by default it's 60 secs. Otherwises, the stage will fail because of long time not response.

Comment: I am facing the exact same error and I am not able to find the solution for it. Did this setting help completing the 1TB terasort? And what was the configuration of your spark cluster?